# The parametric equation $X= V+ t(U -V)$ represents the line through $U$ and $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Show that the parametric equation **X** = **V** +$t$ (**U** $-$ **V**)represents the line through **U** and **V** if **U** and **V** are any two vectors which are not equal.

How can I prove? So, if **U** and **V** are any two vectors which are equal then what can it be?

Comment: Look at the distance between any to points on the line, and check that this is the arclength of the arc between these two points.

Comment: First, do you agree that what you've written represents a line? Second, what happens when $t=0$ and $t=1$?